# how to copy text from a pop up window (gnome)

Tags: copy, paste, electron, popup-ads

I'm coding in electron and when i get an error, it shows it in a pop up window. But i cannot copy the error. Does anyone know a solution? I tried to use Gimagereader to copy text from a screenshot but that doesn´t work. I also tried google docs but that doesnt work either

Comment: In Gnome applications, you can copy text from dialogs to the clipboard.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. If you want a serious answer, take a screenshot of the pop-up window. Otherwise, you have only vague answers.

Comment: Not suitable for this site? Why, Gimagereader is Ubuntu third party software.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your issue. Do you want a solution for how to make your program's error output able to be copied? Or do you want to know of a way to grab a screenshot of the error and convert it to text? If the first, then it's a programming question and you should ask it on Stack Overflow. If the second, then it's fine here. Can you please clarify the situation by [edit]ing your question?